# Spring 3 form validators

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, validation

I have a problem for form validation in a spring 3 mvc application.

It seems everything is set up, but when a bad entry is enetered in the form field it is detected by validator and no error message is shown.

here's the validator

```
@Component
public class SettingsValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return VrSettings.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "applicationBaseUri", "field.required", "field required");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "remoteDnsServiceUri","field.required", "field required");

    VrSettings settings = (VrSettings) target;
    try
    {
        URI uri = new URI(settings.getApplicationBaseUri());
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        errors.rejectValue("applicationBaseUri", "error.invalid.uri", "invalid uri");
    }
    try
    {
        URI uri = new URI(settings.getLocalApplicationBaseURI());
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        errors.rejectValue("localApplicationBaseURI", "error.invalid.uri", "invalid uri");
    }
    try
    {
        URI uri = new URI(settings.getRemoteDnsServiceUri());
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        errors.rejectValue("remoteDnsServiceUri", "error.invalid.uri", "invalid uri");
    }

}
```

}

the controller...

```
@Controller
public class UserInterfaceController {

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
{
    binder.setValidator(new SettingsValidator());
}


@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="ui/settings")
public ModelAndView postSettings(@ModelAttribute("settings") @Valid VrSettings settings, BindingResult result)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("settings");
    mav.addObject("settings", settings);
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        mav.addAllObjects(result.getModel());
        return mav;
    }

    LinkedList<VrSettings> vrSettingsList = persistenceManager.getAll(new VrSettings());
    if(vrSettingsList.isEmpty())
    {
        //do things
    }
    else
    {
               //do things
    }

    return mav;
}

}
```

and finally the JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

```
    <h3>Configuration Parameters</h3>

        <span style="font-weight:bold; color: red">
            <form:errors path="*" />
       </span><br />
    <div class="form">
    <form:form method="post" action="settings" commandName="settings">

            <form:label for="baseuri" path="applicationBaseUri">base URI*</form:label>
            <form:input class="text" path="applicationBaseUri" size="35" name="baseuri"/>

            <form:label for="localbaseuri" path="localApplicationBaseURI">local base URI</form:label>
            <form:input class="text" path="localApplicationBaseURI" size="35" name="localbaseuri"/>

            <form:label for="ldns" path="remoteDnsServiceUri">ldns URI*</form:label>
            <form:input class="text" path="remoteDnsServiceUri" size="35" name="ldns"/>

            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
            </div>

    </form:form>
    </div>

</body>
```

I can't understand what I'm missing.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form:errors path="*" />
```

Needs to know what command object it should operate on. So move this tag inside

```
<form:form method="post" action="settings" commandName="settings">
```

without this the method `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.shouldRender()` for `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag` just returns `SKIP_BODY` because it can't find `BindingResult` for your command object.